# WPF Application still runs in background after closing

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, visual-c#-express-2010

This is slightly related to the question asked here yet the answer does not apply to my case as I am not using threads:

[WPF Not closing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116133/my-wpf-app-still-running-if-i-open-another-window)

I have converted one of my WinForm application to a WPF application, nothing drastic needed to be done except for change a few words to the WPF/C# 4.0 equivalents (MessageBoxButtons to MessageBoxButton, why the one letter difference?).

Anyway, if I run the application through the debugger it runs fine until I come to close it with the "X" button to the top right of the window. The application window closes but I noticed that the debugger still shows the stop icon, checking in the Task Manager confirms it is still running.

I am not running any other threads in the background so I know it's not waiting for something else.

I've only just started with WPF but I assumed that when the user closes the application then it should just...close?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What is your [shutdown mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)? If it's explicit, then it's because you're not explicitly shutting down. If it's main window, it's because you've not assigned the main window to `Application.MainWindow`.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew there were different behaviours for shutting down an application. I simply added " ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose" " to my application's XAML as stated in your link and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 17):

Write this code on application closing button:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown()
```

Comment: I didn't have a closing button but by hitting the x it will call the Closed event and this worked well for me: this.Closed += (s,e) => Application.Current.Shutdown();

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, add this to your App.cs

```
public App()
    {
        ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
    }
```

[Detailed explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992119/wpf-app-doesnt-shut-down-when-closing-main-window)