# WPF App Doesn't Shut Down When Closing Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, window

I'm used to WinForms programming in Visual Studio, but I wanted to give WPF a try.

I added another window to my project, called Window01. The main window is called MainWindow. Before the `public MainWindow()` constructor I declare Window01:

```
Window01 w1;
```

Now I instantiate this window in:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    w1 = new Window01();            
}
```

I have a button where the window is shown: `w1.ShowDialog();`.

The 'funny' thing here is the fact that if I start the application (with debugging) and exit it a few seconds after (I don't do anything in the application), Visual Studio doesn't stop debugging as if the application is still running.

If I move the line `w1 = new Window01();` to the button click method, meaning just above `ShowDialog()`, Visual Studio is behaving properly - that is, the debugging stops when I exit the application.

Why this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

In your `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, try doing this:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);

    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Per this link, you can also set the `ShutdownMode` in XAML:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
    >
</Application>
```

Applications stop running only when the `Shutdown` method of the `Application` is called. Shut down can occur implicitly or explicitly, as specified by the value of the `ShutdownMode` property.

If you set `ShutdownMode` to `OnLastWindowClose`, Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) implicitly calls Shutdown when the last window in an application closes, even if any currently instantiated windows are set as the main window (see MainWindow).

A `ShutdownMode` of `OnMainWindowClose` causes WPF to implicitly call Shutdown when the MainWindow closes, even if other windows are currently open.

The lifetime of some applications may not be dependent on when the main window or last window is closed, or may not be dependent on windows at all. For these scenarios you need to set the `ShutdownMode` property to `OnExplicitShutdown`, which requires an explicit `Shutdown` method call to stop the application. Otherwise, the application continues running in the background.

`ShutdownMode` can be configured declaratively from XAML or programmatically from code.

This property is available only from the thread that created the `Application` object.

---

In your case, the app isn't closing because you're probably using the default `OnLastWindowClose`:

If you set `ShutdownMode` to `OnLastWindowClose`, WPF implicitly calls Shutdown when the last window in an application closes, even if any currently instantiated windows are set as the main window (see `MainWindow`).

Since you're opening a new window, and not closing it, shutdown doesn't get called.

Comment: It's important to note that the override function is best if you've instantiated any other Threads to perform certain tasks.  Stop the Threads in the OnClosed function before shutting done.  Otherwise the Threads stay alive and the app never truly exits.

Comment: I am not sure, if its a good idea to shut down an application, only because MainWindow is closed. Its also possible, that background process is trying to do something like saving to DB, writing into logs, caching things, disconnecting devices etc... At this point, I would find the problem that blocks the application close and fix it. Always organise your applications lifecycle.`Application.Current.Shutdown()` will shutdown the application immediatelly like finishing the process on Taskbar. This is like shooting someone, before he says his last word :).. I would not recommend.

Answer (score 42):

I'm glad you got your answer but for the sake of others I'll answer your question as-well to add some information.

---

### Step 1

First, if you want your program to exit when the main window closes down, you need to specify, since this is not WinForms where this behavior is default.

*(The default in WPF is when the last window closes down)*

**In Code**

Go to your application instance in your entry point (In VS 2012's WPF program the default is nested inside `App.xaml`, so go **inside** it and navigate to `App.xaml.cs` & create a constructor).

In the constructor specify that your [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588794.aspx)'s [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) should be [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode.aspx).`OnLastWindowClose`.

```
    public App()
    {
        ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
    }
```

**In XAML**

Go to your `App.xaml` file that VS 2012 created by default (or create it yourself)
The root is an `Application`, specify inside that your [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588794.aspx)'s [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) should be [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode.aspx).`OnLastWindowClose`.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication27.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
```

If it works, you're done; you can stop reading.

---

### Step 2

If the above didn't work (I guess you wrote the WPF application from scratch), the main window probably isn't known to the application as the main window.
So specify that as-well.

**In Code**

Go to the application's constructor as you did in Step 1, and specify that [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588794.aspx).[`MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx)'s value is your [`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx):

```
MainWindow = mainWindow;
```

**In XAML**

Go to the `Application` XAML as you did in Step 1, and specify that [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588794.aspx).[`MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx)'s value is your [`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx):

```
MainWindow = "mainWindow";
```

---

### Alternative

I don't think this is the best approach, just because WPF doesn't want you to do this (so it has [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588794.aspx)'s [`ShutdownMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)), but you can just use an event / override an event method (OnEventHappened).

Go to the MainWindow's code-behind file and add:

```
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);

        App.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is better then that one which is marked.

Comment: I usually do it this way:  Set `MainWindow` to the main window's instance, set `ShutdownMode` to `ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose`, call `MainWindow.Show()` in callback to `Startup` event of `App`.

This is the most minimal solution I came up with that works as expected at least in .NET Core 3 with WPF.

Answer (score 11):

Because the default [shutdown mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) in a WPF application is OnLastWindowClose, which means the application stops when the last window closes.

When you instantiate a new Window object, it automatically gets added to the [list of windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) in the application. So, the problem was that your application was creating two windows when it started - the MainWindow and the not-yet-shown Window01 - and if you only closed the MainWindow, the Window01 would keep your application running.

Normally, you will create a window object in the same method that is going to call its ShowDialog, and you will create a new window object each time the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this Question when searching for something else and I was surprised that I could not see any of the proposed answers mentioning about `Window.Owner`.

```
    {
       var newWindow = new AdditionalWindow();
       newWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);

       // then later on show the window with Show() or ShowDialog()
    }
```

A call to `Window.GetWindow(this)` is quite useful in View of an MVVM application when you are far down the visual tree not knowing where you have been instantiated, it can be called by supplying any `FrameWork` element (e.g. `UserContol`, `Button`, `Page`).  Obviously if you have a direct reference to the window then use that or even `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

This is quite a powerful relationship that has a number of useful benefits that you might not realise to begin with (assuming you have not specifically coded separate windows to avoided these relationships).

If we call your main window `MainWindow` and the second window as `AdditionalWindow` then....

1. Minimising the `MainWindow` will also minimise `AdditionalWindow`
2. Restoring `MainWindow` will also restore `AdditionalWindow`
3. Closing `MainWindow` will close `AdditionalWindow`, but closing `AdditionalWindow` will not close `MainWindow`
4. `AdditioanlWindow` will never get "lost" under `MainWindow`, i.e. `AddditionalWindow` always shows above `MainWindow` in the z-order if you used `Show()` to display it (quite useful!)

One thing to note though, if you have this relationship, then the `Closing` event on the `AdditionalWindow` is not called, so you'd have to manually iterate over the `OwnedWindows` collection.  e.g.  Create a way to call each window via a new Interface, or base class method.

```
    private void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var window in OwnedWindows)
        {
            var win = window as ICanCancelClosing;  // a new interface you have to create
            e.Cancel |= win.DoYouWantToCancelClosing();
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me, maybe because our project uses Prism.
So ended up using this in the App.XAML.cs

```
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnExit(e);
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something I ran into when I created a second window to act as a dialog box.  When the second window was opened and then closed and then the main window was closed, the app kept running (in the background).  I added (or confirmed) the following in my App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="XXXXXXX.App"
             ...  
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
    <Application.MainWindow >
        <NavigationWindow Source="MainWindow.xaml" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Application.MainWindow>
```

No joy.

So, I finally went into my "MainWindow.xaml" and added a "Closed" property to the Window which went to a "MainWind_Closed" method that looks like the following:

```
 private void MainWind_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach ( Window w in App.Current.Windows )
            {
                if (w.DataContext != this)
                    w.Close();
            }
        }
```

Running through the debugger, it looks like the only window that shows up is the window I created as a dialog--in other words, the foreach loop only finds one window--the dialog, not the main.

I had "this.Close()" running in the method that closed the dialog, and I had a "dlgwin.Close()" that came after the "dlgwin.ShowDialog()", and that didn't work.  Not even a "dlgwin = null".

So, why wouldn't that dialog close without this extra stuff?  Oh well.  This works.