# How do you shutdown a WPF app when the "X" button is clicked

Tags: c#-4.0, application-shutdown

I'm new to WPF and have noticed that my application keeps running after I click the "X" button to exit the window. I've programmed GUI's before, so I know that this is common. However, when I look into the issue, whatever solutions I find do not seem to make any sense.

I've found this [Applicaton.ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) solution, but it seems like I am not implementing it correctly. I want my application to shutdown "OnMainWindowClose". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543704/wpf-application-still-runs-in-background-after-closing) is a question that is pretty much the same as mine that I don't think was explained clearly enough in the accepted answer.

Following the `Application.ShutdownMode` solution, I have this in my MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="CartToolsPrototype1.Window1" Background="White"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    Title="{DynamicResource CartTools}" Height="802" Width="950" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
    <Window.Resources>

        <Application
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            StartupUri="Window1.xaml"
            ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"
            >
            </Application>
```

The compiler gives me an error that says, "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them." What exactly am I doing wrong here, and how can I correctly implement my shutdown function?

Thank you.

Comment: This most likely isn't a WPF specific problem. My guess would be that you start a thread and it is neither marked as background nor finished when you try to close your application.

Comment: Can't I just remove the wpf tag instead of starting a totally new thread?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't that my ShutdownMode isn't coded correctly? In my App.xaml file I have `ShutdownMode="OneMainWindowClose"`, but the program continues in the background when I click "x"

Comment: I found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't put `Application` tag into your `Window`. In your solution you have `app.xaml` where you should put your:

```
ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"
```

and quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx):

> MainWindow is automatically set with a reference to the first Window object to be instantiated in the AppDomain.

Comment: OOOOH, okay. Lightbulb... I put it in that file, but my Window1 must not be set as the "main window" because the x button doesn't close out the application when I close the main window.

Comment: What is your `StartupUri` in `app.xaml`. Is it your `MainWindow`?

Comment: StartupUri is "Window1.xaml"

Comment: My solution just tells you how to change `ShutdownMode` and deal with compile error you're having but, as @GarryVass suggested, your app should close with default settings any way and I would suggest to do some more debugging to see if there's anything blocking shutdown.

Comment: I marked this as my answer, because technically it did solve my compiler error, but I did find an error during debugging that was preventing shutdown.