# WPF application process does not terminate

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, terminate

We wrote a wpf application using .NET 3.5. We use the CANopen protocal and log4net. The application starts a few tasks all of which are completed. I checked this by writing a message to the log file - everything was ok. Sometimes the application process terminates immediatelly, sommetimes it takes a few seconds and sometimes it does not terminate. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: This seems like way too little to go off of, well, at least for me...

Comment: The non-determinism might have to do with garbage collection, as in the lack of garbage collection happening keeping the application alive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Application still runs in background after closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543704/wpf-application-still-runs-in-background-after-closing)

Comment: Can you reproduce this within or attach a debugger?  You should then be able to see which thread is keeping the process open.

Comment: @H.B.: What can i do in this case?

Comment: `GC.Collect()` forces garbage collection, but do you know when to trigger that, i.e. when all tasks are done?

Comment: You can use tools for getting state of threads and executing methods. Here is my tool - https://github.com/REASY/ProcInfo4Net. Usage is simple: ProcInfo4Net.exe ###ProccessId###